# How to evaluate circulation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am having some trouble with the following question:

Solve for the circulation in five different ways for the velocity field $$\bar v=(e^{-x^2}-yz)\hat i+(e^{-y^2}-xz+2x)\hat j+(e^{-z^2})\hat k$$ around the curve C, the intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and $z=x^2+y^2$

My thoughts/attempts:

First of all, the intersection seems to be when $z=-2$ or $z=1$ but I am assuming we could consider the $z=1$ part above the xy plane to get the real component.

I thought, Circulation $= \int_{C}\bar v \bullet \hat T = \int_{C}\bar  v \bullet \frac{dR}{dS}dS=\int_{C} \bar v \bullet dR$ also , stokes thereom saying it is equal to $\iint_{Rxy} \nabla \times F \bullet \hat k$

So we have a sphere of radius $\sqrt{2}$ and it intersects the paraboloid at $z=1$ ie when $x^2+y^2=1$ so my first thought would be that I need to parametrize this curve some how.

I also calculated, Curl $\bar F$$= (x,-y,2)$

I dont think it is correct but if I had to try to parametrize I would say $r(t)=(cost,sint,1)$,  $0 \le t \le 2\pi$, and so $r'(t)=(-sint,cost,0)$

then I could plug into to solve $F(r(t))$ and evaluate $\int_{c} F(r(t)) \bullet r'(t) dt$, etc.

But I am just not confident in my work, or the other methods etc, I am looking for help.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I can count to five. Your parametrization of the curve $C$ is correct, so just evaluate the line integral directly.

You can also apply Stokes's Theorem in various ways, taking different surfaces (being careful about orientation) with the same boundary curve $C$. Assuming we orient $C$ counterclockwise as viewed from above,

• You can fill $C$ in with the disk $x^2+y^2\le 1$, $z=1$.

• You can consider the spherical surface *above* $C$ (oriented with unit normal pointing outward).

• You can consider the spherical surface *below* $C$ (oriented with unit normal pointing inward).

• You can consider the surface of the paraboloid *below* $C$ (oriented with unit normal pointing upward).

Good luck with all these calculations! :)

**EDIT**: Since you've asked, I'll do one of these to illustrate. We wish to find the flux of $\text{curl}\,\vec F$ outward across that portion $S$ of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ with $z\ge 1$. We parametrize in spherical coordinates:
$$\vec r(u,v)=\sqrt2(\sin u\cos v,\sin u\sin v,\cos u), \quad 0\le u\le \pi/4, 0\le v\le 2\pi.$$
Then you compute the fundamental vector cross product
$$\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v} = 2\sin u(\sin u\cos v,\sin u\sin v,\cos u).$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\iint_S \text{curl}\,\vec F\cdot\vec n dS &= \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi} \vec F(\vec r(u,v))\cdot \left(\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial v}\right)du\,dv \\
&= \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi} (\sqrt2\sin u\cos v,-\sqrt2\sin u\sin v, 2)\cdot 2\sin u(\sin u\cos v,\sin u\sin v,\cos u)\,du\,dv \\
&= 2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{2\pi} \big(\sqrt2(\sin^3u)(\cos^2v-\sin^2v) + 2\cos u\sin u\big)du\,dv \\
&= 4 (2\pi) \int_0^{\pi/4}\cos u\sin u\,du = 8\pi\big(\frac14\big)=2\pi.
\end{align*}
(Note that $\int_0^{2\pi} (\cos^2v-\sin^2v)\,dv = 0$.)

Comment: Hi thanks, could you please explain what you mean by "your parametrization needs to have z=1 in it", in my post I have r(t)=(cost,sint,1) , is that the incorrect parametrization? Thanks

Comment: Oh I see yes that did look a bit confusing, thanks for updating. I am going to work on this more in a bit and I will update

Comment: I am just still confused about how to actually evauluate such. Do you think you could show me of those ways and I will then try the rest? For example, how would I do it for the spherical surface above C, what does that mean?

Comment: Much appreciated, my last question is; How does one know which order to take the cross product to get the normal, ie, how did you know to do u cross v instead of v cross u

Comment: This is why I made reference to the orientation of the surface in the four different examples — Stokes's Theorem dictates that the orientation of the surface must be compatible with the orientation of the boundary curve. You need to make sure that the cross product points in the correct direction (in or out, up or down).